# How Can I Fix Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content (in blogger)

Tags: javascript, performance, mobile, web, blogger

I'm using blogger and I'm getting this error;

I want to increase the speed of my web site.

That is the problem

[image: xxx]

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a tour of the help center to see how to ask a good question and what sorts of question you can ask on this site

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google's recommendations:
[for JS](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) and [for CSS](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)